How to tell if an offset term is used from GLM model summary in Statsmodels?
I am currently working on Poisson regressions with offset terms via the GLM function in Statsmodels, but I think the same issue exists for the GLM function in R as the model summary is quite similar.
I created 2 simple models, one with an offset term and one without. The output from both is below.
It appears to me that there is no indication that an offset term was or was not used in either model. Furthermore, I searched the attributes from the GLMResult that Statsmodel provides and none of them showed an offset term present.



It looks like in statsmodels the only way to check is to see if the model instance (not the results instance) has an offset attribute. Similarly, AFAICS, there is no indication either whether exposure or weights have been used. Issue seems to have gotten lost https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/2002
